# Sitecore databases missing after SIFLess install

Tags: sql, database, powershell, installation, sitecore

I am using SIFLess to install Sitecore 9.1 Update 1 on my local machine in order to get started with development with my team. However, the install is not creating certain databases on my system that are needed to get up and running, most notably the Reporting database. This of course causes problems when I deploy code from my team's repo to my local instance as it references these databases. I see that the SIFLess-generated PowerShell script has calls to a 'RemoveDatabase' function that references these databases in the uninstall method, but no code to create them in the first place during an install. The missing databases are:

MarketingAutomation
Messaging
Processing.Pools
ProcessingEngineStorage
ProcessingEngineTasks
ReferenceData
Reporting
Xdb.Collection.Shard0 and 1
Xdb.Collection.ShardMapManager

These are what I have gleaned from the uninstall logic in the PowerShell script generated by SIFLess. Again, no logic exists to create them in the first place in the install section. My team members all have these databases on their systems. What am I doing wrong? I am a Sitecore novice here.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using the good package. You have to download the XP package, not XM. (Just to be sure here). Afterwards, the Database installation are done with DacPac found within the Sitecore Web Deploy Package ( *.scwdp).

Please, also make sure that within this scdwp you can see (can double click or extract) the database missing :

- MarketingAutomation
- Messaging
- Processing.Pools
- ProcessingEngineStorage
- ProcessingEngineTasks
- ReferenceData

And do the same with the xConnect SCWDP, and make sure you see the databse missing there :

- Xdb.Collection.Shard0
- Xdb.Collection.Shard1
- Reporting

Sometimes, if you have tried the installation script more than once, you can have some undesired behavior. You are possibly trying to go forward with the wrong certificates. Also, some services were actually created on previous installation attempts.

Here is what I think should help you get through.

**Clean your workspace**

- Remove your databases that are related to the installation if exists.
- Remove your certificates (using certlm -> you can type in your windows search bar "cert" and then you should be able to pick "Manage computer Certificate".

  - On the left sidebar, Click on Personal > Certificates.

    - Remove your installation-related certificates

      - nameOfYourInstallation.identityserver
      - nameOfYourInstallation.sc
      - nameOfYourInstallation.xconnect
- Open your Windows Services Manager (you can type in your windows search bar "services" and select the services app)

  - You should be able to see those services :

    - Sitecore Marketing Automation Engine - nameOfYourInstallation(might be one of your previous install)
    - Sitecore Processing Engine - nameOfYourInstallation
    - Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - nameOfYourInstallation.

      - Write those down. Keep your service app open.
  - Using NSSM (probably installed already from some of your previous installed, if not, can use chocolatey ( https://chocolatey.org/packages/NSSM ) remove those services.
  - in a cmd : nssm remove serviceName

    - Note that you can remove them by right clicking etc. I just prefer the nssm way.
- When its done, restart your computer (some services and in a state of removal, that needs a restart to be completely removed)
- Try to install again.

Hope it helps, cheers !